# Split a string by capital letters in DataFormatString C# - MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I have a Data Gridview that uses a DB from MySQL.

I have many values in many entries in DB such as:

- **UnitedStates**
- **UnitedKingdom**

  and the output need to be -->
- **United States**
- **United Kingdom**

I need to put a code to DataFormatString.
What is the code that I need to insert in the **DataFormatString** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can split the string then combine the chars :)

```
static string CapitalSplit(string str)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (char.IsUpper(c))
            result.Append(' ').Append(c);
        else
            result.Append(c);
    }

    return result.ToString().TrimStart(' ');
}
```

**Test:**

CapitalSplit("AaaBbb");

**Output:**
Aaa Bbb

Comment: But i dont understand, after i put this code in the code behind, do i need to call it like this: **DataFormatString="{CapitalSplit}"**  ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx . It seems that you cannot use a simple DataFormatString to achieve this . You need to write a function to change the data format manually .

Comment: @YuvalSP, his function does not work like this. To use it you must alter values somewhere between receiving them from database and displaying them to user. Then you don't have to use any DataFormatString.

Comment: @rufanov - what is the function that I need to write in MySQL to split the words?

Comment: @YuvalSP, words can be splitted in MySQL using LEFT()/MID()/RIGHT()/SUBSTRING()/SUBSTRING_INDEX() functions, then they can be concatenated using "||" operator. But it's very simple functions. If you want to format this string at MySQL side using this format, then you most likely will need to write own user defined function(UDF). Standard MySQL text manipulation functions is pretty restricted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard format string that can add spaces between capital letters. To do this using DataFormatString, you must write own class that implement [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ICustomFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) interfaces to handle some new formatting specifier. Then you can make BoundField to use your class for doing formatting. DataFormatString will include only your custom format specifier(something like "{0:SplitByCaptialLetters}").